# How to specify nested parameters in the routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In routes.rb I have described how the search will look like this

```
match "results//:transaction/:city(.:format)" => "search#index", :as => :seo_search_index
```

which generates me this kind of routes

```
seo_search_index         /results/:transaction/:city(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"search"}
```

And the params object is filled with

```
params[:transaction]
params[:city]
params[:zip5]
```

But I want the param object to be filled like this

```
params[:search][:transaction]
params[:search][:city]
params[:search][:zip5]
```

Is there a way to specify this like this

Just an example:

```
match "results//:search[transaction]/:search[city](.:format)" => "search#index", :as => :seo_search_index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help routing filter you can make what ever you want with the urls https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way to tell the Rails routing system that you want your parameters nested. You could work around this issue with a before filter in your controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    params[:search] = params.slice(:transaction, :city, :zip5)
  end
end
```

**Update**

To answer your real question, you could do either:

```
seo_search_index_url(@search)
```

or

```
seo_search_index_url(@search.slice(:transaction, :city, :zip5))
```

depending on whether the `@search` hash contains only the keys you want or some additional ones.

Comment: actually I want to opposite think. To make rails extract the parameters from the the object I pass to the seo_search_index_url  method.

For example:

seo_search_index_url(:search => @search)

and to get

results/buy/Sofia

Comment: you should update your question then, else you may have more wrong answers

Comment: The question is OK, because it is "How to specify nested parameters in the routes" and not how to read them.

Comment: This would work, but will pollute the params with the search keys/values, and you can't do seo_search_index_url(:search => @search)   useful when you want to make Search.new(params[:search]), use simple_form/formtastic/form_for @search, etc...

Maybe there is cleaner way of doing this

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry then, I exhausted my answers :-)